# Matrix-like survey for client

Tags: matrix

I have a membership site where, besides their location and other contact information, part of the member profile will include a summary of their areas of practice.  This summary will be a list of what areas their practice covers (I’ll call them service 1, service 2, service 3, etc.) and what their expertise level is - considerate, moderate, limited or none (meaning they don’t specialize in that area).  This list of services is currently at about 40 items, and the client needs to be able to add/remove services from the list at will.  In addition, the member will need to update their own areas of practice through a front-end SAEF.  Below is an example of what the might look like.

In addition, someone from the public could use this information to search for a member who does "considerate work in service 1".

Originally I thought a Matrix field would be perfect due to its flexibility. However, when setting it up, I don’t think it will work as I thought.  So now I’m back to the drawing board on how to set this up.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions?

Todd

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option would be to use [Zoo Visitor](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/zoo-visitor) to be able to work with the members as channel entries.

Then you could add the list of services to the zoo visitor channel as individual select fields. So for example you would have a zoo visitor channel that contains all the members as entries, and on each entry you would have the contact info as well as the individual fields that make up your list of services. Going this route should also make editing through the front end channel:form easy.

I think you could also go a similar route just using custom member fields, but in your case you might really appreciate the flexibility with having the members in channel entries.

Comment: Thank you for your comment (and sorry for the delay - I didn't see a notice that you had replied).  The site is already going to use Zoo Visitor to manage the members so this is pointing me in the right direction.  The only issue with adding them as individual fields is that there could be 40-50 questions for them to answer for this "survey". Would that be an issue? Also, I would like the client to be able to add new fields as needed without bothering me.  But that's probably not that big of a deal.

Comment: I don't see that it's an issue for having all the question fields on a single channel as far as speed, but maybe someone else will chime in on that. And having them all on a single entry is the easiest way I know to let a member quickly edit their own fields via channel form on a single form.